Scroll horizontal scroll view to center of screen
I have created a HorizontalScrollView in which i have to added n number of views dynamically. also i want to achieve automatic scrolling to a specific view at the center of screen like below picture.

I have tried getting on clicked view and scroll to it using below method, it scrolls but i want it at center of screen.


m_dates_horizontal_scroll.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        m_dates_horizontal_scroll.smoothScrollTo(m_selected_date.getLeft(), m_selected_date.getTop());
    }
});

i got below results with above code.


maybe you can try : m_selected_date.getLeft() - (yourScrollViewWidthInPX/2)  + (yourItemWidthWithPaddingInPX/2)
